# flatbuffers c++, I wonder if multiple tables in 1 fbs file is possible

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

Multiple tables and multiple root_type in 1 fbs file is possible in javascript.

examle::

```
table Login {
    name:string;
    password:string;
}

table Attack {
    damage:short;
}
```

2 root_type table was made and 2 getRoot function(getRootAsLogin, getRootAsAttack) was made.

But 1 getRootAs function was made when written in C++ using the same schema.

How do I get two getRootAs function in 1 fbs file?
split one file into one table?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `GetRoot<Login>()` and `GetRoot<Attack>()` if you need other roots than what was declared for `root_type`.

Splitting into 2 files, each with their own `root_type` declaration, will also work, if you prefer the generated functions.